# Error while running weka3.7.4 package manager

Tags: java, jdbc, package, weka

when i am running weka.jar 3.7.4 (gui on windows7) in tools>Package Manager it shows error... "There was a problem establishing the package meta data cache.We'll try to use the repository directly."

```
weka.core.WekaPackageRepositoryURL = http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/package
```

MetaData
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): RmiJdbc.RJDriver - Warning, not in CLASSPA
TH?
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): jdbc.idbDriver - Warning, not in CLASSPATH
?
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver - Warning, not in
CLASSPATH?
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): com.mckoi.JDBCDriver - Warning, not in CLA
SSPATH?
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver - Warning, not in CL
ASSPATH?
[KnowledgeFlow] Loading properties and plugins...
[KnowledgeFlow] Initializing KF...

Error is

```
ava.net.UnknownHostException: weka.sourceforge.net
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.packageManagement.DefaultPackageManager.getRepositoryPackageMetaDataOnlyAsZip(Unknown Source)
at weka.core.WekaPackageManager.refreshCache(WekaPackageManager.java:796)
at weka.core.WekaPackageManager.establishCacheIfNeeded(WekaPackageManager.java:737)
at weka.gui.PackageManager$EstablishCache.doInBackground(PackageManager.java:285)
at weka.gui.PackageManager$EstablishCache.doInBackground(PackageManager.java:256)
at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

error that occure on pop up is

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: www.cs.waikato.ac.nz
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.packageManagement.DefaultPackageManager.getRepositoryPackageMetaDataOnlyAsZip(Unknown Source)
at weka.core.WekaPackageManager.refreshCache(WekaPackageManager.java:796)
at weka.core.WekaPackageManager.establishCacheIfNeeded(WekaPackageManager.java:737)
at weka.gui.PackageManager$EstablishCache.doInBackground(PackageManager.java:285)
at weka.gui.PackageManager$EstablishCache.doInBackground(PackageManager.java:256)
at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this](http://list.waikato.ac.nz/pipermail/wekalist/2011-February/051119.html).

1. Create a file `\WEKA_HOME\props\PackageRepository.props` and
2. insert the line `weka.core.wekaPackageRepositoryURL=http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/packageMetaData`.

Under Windows `WEKA_HOME=C:\Users\YOUR_USER\wekafiles\`